# htaccess and polish phrases - friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, polish, phrases

I have to create a friendly url with polish phrases. 
Finally, my .htaccess should accept all letters (and polish letters too), numbers, plus(+) and minus(-).
Can you help me?

Thanks!

My url:

```
cat-3,woj-4,Kraków
```

My htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^cat-([0-9]+),woj-([0-9]+),(['/^\p{L}+$/ui']+)/?$ show_list_adverts.php?mode=searching&cat_id=$1&search_province=$2&search_city=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: My url: `cat-3,woj-4,Kraków`

My htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^cat-([0-9]+),woj-([0-9]+),(['/^\p{L}+$/ui']+)/?$ show_list_adverts.php?mode=searching&cat_id=$1&search_province=$2&search_city=$3 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `.`?

```
RewriteRule ^cat-([0-9]+),woj-([0-9]+),(.+)/?$ show_list_adverts.php?mode=searching&cat_id=$1&search_province=$2&search_city=$3 [L]
```